# Getting a Google Oauth access token for web site I don't own

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, google-oauth

This is kind of a repost from my previous question, but its different enough that I thought a separate one would be ok. What I'm trying to do is get an access token for a third party web site through Google's Oauth. I don't really understand Oauth that well though, and am kind of stumbling around in the dark.

I looked online and found some tutorials on getting access tokens for APIs, but they all seem to only be for Google APIs, or for large websites. I created developer console authentication credentials, and put them into client_secrets.json.

(This is all Python by the way, but if a different language would allow me to do this I will happily use that instead)

```
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('client_secrets.json',
                                                  scopes=["openid"]
                                                  )

flow.run_local_server(port=8080, prompt='consent')

credentials = flow.credentials
print(credentials.to_json())
```

The problem is getting scopes for it, which I believe allow the token to be used to access different services? In that case I think I would then need a scope specific to the site I am trying to log into. I looked at the requests that get sent when I click on the login with google button, and the scope seems to just be email, but that then gives an error if I put that as the scope.

> Warning: Scope has changed from "email" to "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email openid"

Using openid as the scope and then trying the access token gets me a not signed in error.

If someone could help or even just explain Oauth to me that would be really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

OAuth is a way for the data owner to protect their data. Eg to call company X's API you must first authenticate via company X's authorization server, to get an access token. This might require `scope=sales` if the API deals with a sales business area.

A website that wants to call company X's sales API (this website may or may not also be owned by company X) would therefore run an authorization redirect and request `scope=sales`.

Company X's authorization server could offer an authentication option to sign in via Google. However, from company X's viewpoint, Google access tokens are `foreign access tokens`. They are not suitable for company X to use to protect its own data. Therefore the authorization server issues its own access tokens and does not return those from Google to the website.

Therefore you seem to be missing the authorization server component that is needed in order to implement OAuth correctly. This is introduced in the original [RFC6749 document](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749).

Comment: Thanks, so I looked through all the requests in burp suite, and I think i have identified the scopes, and I can see it send a bunch of information in a request, which then returns another link that loads the authenticated website, and then there is a different token that it uses, as you said. What do you think i should try next to use the google token to get a normal one?